# Using "Select New" in HQL with join complaining "Path expected for join"

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 related Entity classes and want to define another non-Entity class simply contains the 2 Entity classes so that I can using HQL to load the 2 Entity Classes with Join.  Here are the codes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Conversation", schema = "aaa", catalog = "xxx")
public class Conversation implements Serializable {

    private String conversationGuid;

...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Ticket", schema = "dbo", catalog = "MyTime")
public class Ticket implements Serializable {

    private String ticketGuid;

    private String conversationGuid;
...

}
```

Non Entity POJO:

```
public class Conversation_Ticket {
    private Conversation convo;
    private Ticket ticket;

    public Conversation_Ticket(Conversation convo, Ticket ticket) {
        super();
        this.convo = convo;
        this.ticket = ticket;
    }   
}
```

DAO to make HQL query:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().addFile("/Users/csi/git/mytime-acr/src/main/resources/Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml");

Query query = getSession().createQuery(
        "select new Conversation_Ticket(convo, tic)"
        + "from Conversation as convo left outer join fetch Ticket as tic on convo.Conversation_GUID = tic.Conversation_GUID where agentGuidCurrent = :agentGuid and workState = :workState");

query.setParameter("agentGuidCurrent", agentGuid);
query.setParameter("workState", workState);
List list = query.list();
```

When the createQuery() is called, it basically throw the following exception:
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select new Conversation_Ticket(convo, tic)from com.cs.mytime.acr.model.Conversation as convo left outer join fetch Ticket as tic on convo.Conversation_GUID = tic.Conversation_GUID where agentGuidCurrent = :agentGuid and workState = :workState]

Seems like Hibernate simply doesn't recognize the Conversation_Ticket POJO and expected some object level relationship between Conversation & Ticket.

Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping>
    <import class="com.cs.mytime.acr.model.aggregate.Conversation_Ticket" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And I did tried to put Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml as mapping resources in hibernate.cfg.xml as follows:

```
<mapping resource="/Users/csi/git/mytime-acr/src/main/resources/Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml"/>
```

But it complains about couldn't find the Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml even though I have defined /Users/csi/git/mytime-acr/src/main/resources in CLASSPATH of my environment.

Appreciate anybody who can give me some pointers on how to resolve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a special directory layout. Assuming `src` is a source folder in Eclipse, it will copy all the non-Java files to the classes or bin directory (or whatever directory name you chose for the compiled classes), and the `Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml` should be directly under `src`, since you're telling Hibernate to load it from the root of the `classpath`:

```
cfg.addResource("Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml");
```

If you place it in main/resources, the code to load it should be

```
cfg.addResource("main/resources/Conversation_Ticket.hbm.xml");
```

Why don't you use your own package hierarchy, and thus use the following directory tree:

```
src
  com
    rcook
      myapp
```